# Cómo cambiar el color de una fila en un tabla con KivyMD y Python 3 si cumple determinada condición?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Chicos suponiendo que tengo una condición If en la cual se evalua si la suma de la fila es 8, para cambiar el color de la fila, existe alguna forma de lograrlo?

Ejemplo de código:

```
data_fila = [(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2)]
data_columna = [
            ('Valor 1', dp(14)),
            ('Valor 2', dp(14)),
            ('Valor 3', dp(14)),
            ('Valor 4', dp(14)),
            ]
 
self.data_table = MDDataTable(
    size_hint = (.99, .75),
    pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.6},
    rows_num = 31,
    column_data = data_columna,
    row_data= data_fila,
)

self.button_pdf = MDFloatingActionButton(
    icon = 'file-outline',
    pos_hint = {'center_x': .92, 'center_y': .22},
)

self.root.add_widget(self.data_table)
self.root.add_widget(self.button_pdf)
```